# Doubt in proof 1.37 In functional analysis by Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I had done proof of topology induced by separating family of seminorm
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I do not understand b) converse part that if p(E) is bounded for all p then E is bounded**

Please any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in E$ then $\frac x n \in V(p_i,n_i)$ for each $i$ because $p_i(\frac x n)=\frac  1 n p_i(x)<M_i\frac  1 n<\frac 1 {n_i}$. This proves that  $\frac x n \in \cap_iV(p_i,n_i) \subseteq U$. Thus $E \subseteq nU$ as required.